# Spring WebClient multipart/form-data request, Could not able to send file

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-webclient

Im trying to hit an endpoint which accepts multipart/file request via WebClient, code as follows

```
 WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(urlServer).build();

    List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<>();
    form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "myname"));

    MultipartBodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    form.forEach(k -> bodyBuilder.part(k.getName(), k.getValue(), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
     
     // file 
    File file = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("abc.yaml").getFile());
    bodyBuilder.part("attachmentName",   file);


    String response = webClient.post()
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(bodyBuilder.build())).exchange()
            .block()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();
```

Hit to the desired endpoint is success and 'name' filed value is retrieved as given. But the file data is empty.

I also tired

```
byte[] templateContent = org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(
new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("abc.yaml").getFile()));

bodyBuilder.part("attachmentName",   new ByteArrayResource(templateContent));
```

I could not find where I am going wrong. Any help.

Answer (score 3):

I did it in wong way, File should be given as a resource, Code as follows

```
 public static Resource getTestFile() {
        return new FileSystemResource(new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\abc.docx"));
    }
```

MutipartBody builder

```
bodyBuilder.part("attachmentName",   getTestFile());
```